# Flutter not reflecting changes

Tags: flutter

I am testing my first flutter project, this is a simple app to test navigation from one activity to the other. Currently, only the first activity is displaying but after hot reloading is when the changes are reflected, that is I can go from activity a to be. I have tried running the app and even building it but the changes aren't reflecting, only by hot reload.

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
runApp(new MaterialApp(
home:new HomePage(),
routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
  "/SecondPage":(BuildContext context) => new SecondPage()
}
));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return new Scaffold(
 appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Homepage"),backgroundColor: 
Colors.deepOrange),
 body: new Container(
   child: new Center(
     child: new Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         new IconButton(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
          iconSize: 50.0,
          onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/SecondPage");},
         ),
         new Text("Tap Me")
       ],
     ),
   ),
 ),
 );
 }
 }

 class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return new Scaffold(
 appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("SecondPage"),backgroundColor: 
 Colors.deepOrange),
 body: new Container(
   child: new Center(
     child: new Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         new IconButton(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
          iconSize: 50.0,
          onPressed: null,
         ),
         new Text("Tap Me")
       ],
     ),
   ),
   ),
  );
 }
 }
```

What could be the issue here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: Does running `flutter clean` change anything?

Comment: Yes that actually does the trick!, it simply deletes the build directory and generates an entire new app

Comment: It's a known issue that currently `flutter clean` is often necessary.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by :
**Cleaning the project and rebuild it.** Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61202724/10031056

Comment: I did flutter clean and did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I handle this issue with this steps.

1. I open Android Studio and run device from here.
2. After device loaded, I'm totally closing android studio then start Visual Studio Code.
3. In main.dart I puesh F5 for runing project.
4. Hot reload now active and all changes can be seen instantly.