# Flutter hot reloading is not working to display changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two files, `main.dart` and `sections.dart`.

I have defined a few widgets in `section.dart` and used them in `main.dart` file, when I run `flutter run` command changes are displayed on screen, but when I press `R` to hot reload, nothing changes on screen.

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sections.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Share IDEASS',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('IDEASs'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
           labelsSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Sections.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Share IDEAS',

    );
  }
}

Column labelSectionMethod(color,IconData icon, String label,String numbers){
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Icon(icon, color:color),
      Container(
        child: Text(label,
        style: TextStyle(color: color
        ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child:Text(numbers,
      style:TextStyle(color:color
      ),
      ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

    Widget labelsSection=Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        labelSectionMethod(Colors.red,Icons.supervised_user_circle,"IDEASS","35"),
        labelSectionMethod(Colors.red,Icons.favorite,"LIKE","22"),
        labelSectionMethod(Colors.red,Icons.data_usage,"STREAK","12"),
      ],
    ),
    );
```

Maybe because I am repeating:

```
 return MaterialApp(
title: 'Share IDEAS',
    );
```

in `sections.dart`, or something to do with main function.

> **UPDATE:**

i moved content of sections.dart file in main.dart file still hot reload is not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After moving a file to another directory, Android Studio changed my imports to absolute paths.

```
import 'file:///C:/Users/svenv/AndroidStudioProjects/sample_screen_collection/lib/welcome/reading_list_card.dart';
```

i had to change it to this

```
import 'package:samplescreencollection/components/reading_list_card.dart';
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you have change a lot of code, added states, changed a widget from stateless to state full, etc. Preforming a hot restart (ctrl +F5) will fix this issue. 
If this seems to not work still, try removing the app from your phone/simulator/emulator (closing the app, and deleting it) and running debug/flutter run again. This should fix your issue

Answer (score 3):

There have been issue reported to Flutter regarding this,https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17155#issue-319238844

Basically it's like Flutter is not properly identifying the changes in order to generate updated build files (my personal understanding):

> **Solution**

*Simple solution is Clean the project and rebuild it.*

I'm using Android studio Android Studio 3.6, Following steps illustrate how to clean the flutter project

1. Navigate to **Tools** in navigationbar
2. Select **Flutter** > **Flutter Clean**

[image]

3. Finally **Run the Project** again by clicking the green playicon

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes flutter gets confused with large amounts of changes, and you need to perform a restart, especially when interacting with the entire `App` or `main` function.

You can press`Ctrl+C` to kill the `flutter run` process, and try launching it again. Additionally, if you run Flutter through IntelliJ or Android Studio, the flutter plugin includes a "Hot Restart" feature which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: there must be some reason, any changes in main.dart files are showing up, but when  i change anything in section.dart no changes display. on hot reload.

Comment: The way you've got this laid out means that only changes in `Widget labelsSection=Container(...` should have any effect on the app at all. Also, you have a duplicate definition of `MyApp` in sections - that isn't getting used, and you should probably rename it so you don't confuse yourself.

Comment: whats solution? please

Comment: I would say the best solution is to move whatever you need from `sections` over to `main`, and remove the `sections` file entirely until you are more comfortable with Flutter development, because the way you are approaching the file structure is incorrect.

Comment: i want to keep main file clean.

Comment: I understand, but the fact that you have more than one instance of `MaterialApp` in your project is a big red flag. Start small with all the widgets in the `main` file, and when you have not reload working again, THEN break them apart. Also, for the record, the `MyApp` in `sections` is not being used at all and is just creating issues.

Comment: i deleted section.dart and used those sections, in main file still hot reload is not working.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was - Flutter would neither hot reload nor stop on a break-point nor even provide fresh builds to Android emulator, whereas iOS was fine.

I tried suggestions from above but nothing really worked, spent a day on these things.I upgraded from Android Studio 3.x to 4.1 and nothing changed.

What worked for me was:

- Create a totally new Flutter sample project.
- Validate it works - new versions are deployed, debugging and hot reloads work
- Transfer my project into this new project. This pretty much involved replace of the lib and .git folders and manual updates of pubspec.yaml, AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist (manual file updates took most of the effort, but still much less time than my several day attempts to make things work again)
- Verify everything works.